# Echo img inside a element

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to echo an img tag inside an a element. The code below works, but outputs the closing tag of the img on the frontend. Why is this happening?

The code is inside an if statement.

```php
<?php 
echo  '
      <a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">
        <img src="'.woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'"  />
      </a>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the code you gave

Comment: *"but outputs the closing tag of the img on the frontend"* - Can you demonstrate what specifically you mean by that?  When you view the source in the browser (*not* the DOM explorer, but the raw source returned by the server), what specifically does this emit?

Comment: Can you state clearly what result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your code inside the loop I think you should use it this way:

```
<?php echo  '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a>'; ?>
```

I just removed the `<img />` tag.